# No scroll bar in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, scrollbar

I'm trying to create basic admin interface for my app where everything should be display all the time except one div, block, should be scrollable when overflowed

Here's html:

```
<div class="all">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="logo">a</div>
        <div class="body">b</div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="left">c</div>
        <div class="right">
            <div class="block">
                <div class="one">A</div>
                <div class="two">B</div>
                <div class="three">C</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and css:

```
    body
    {
        position:fixed; 
        top:0px; 
        left:0px;
        bottom:0px; 
        right:0px;  
        margin:0px;
    }

    .all
    {
        position: relative;
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .header
    {
        display: table-row;
        position: relative;
        height: 50px;
    }

    .header .logo
    {
        position: relative;
        display: table-cell;
        background-color: red;

    }

    .header .body
    {
        position: relative;
        display: table-cell;
        background-color: yellow;
    }

    .content
    {
        position: relative;
        display: table-row;
    }
    .content .left
    {
        position: relative;
        display: table-cell;
        height: 100%;
        width: 150px;
        background-color: green;
    }
    .content .right
    {
        position: relative;
        display: table-cell;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: blue;
    }
    .block
    {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }

    .one, .two, .three
    {
        border: 1px solid black;
        height: 500px;
    }
    .one
    {
        background-color: aliceblue;
    }
    .two
    {
        background-color: aqua;
    }
    .three
    {
        background-color: brown;
    }
```

I encoutred one problem, in IE, Chrome i see scrollbar, but not in Firefox. I created JS fiddle, so you can see:

[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/cjzV6/)

Can someone help me?

Comment: Change this class: .one {
    background-color: aliceblue;
    overflow : auto;
}

Comment: didn't worked on my firefox...

Comment: The problem is you've got `height: 100%` on `.block`. If you can give it a fixed height it'll solve it.

Comment: if i give it a fixed height, i would need to use javascript to make it on whole screen on different devices...is there another solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing to `position:absolute` on `block` class  does solves the problem you can have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cjzV6/2/)